# Adding labels at the appropriate aggregation levels of the query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem is to format properly the query result by adding labels at the appropriate
aggregation levels of the query.

Here is the Oracle SQL code:

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(CITY.COUNTRY), 'Summary-total:') VISITED_COUNTRY, 
       NVL(TO_CHAR(CITY.NAME), 'Summary-country:')  CITY, 
       NVL(TO_CHAR(ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME), 'Summary-city:') TYPE,
       SUM(VISIT.NUMBER_OF_VISITORS) VISITORS, 
       SUM(VISIT.PROFIT) AS PROFIT
FROM VISIT
       JOIN CITY ON VISIT.ID_CITY = CITY.ID_CITY 
       JOIN ACCOMMODATIONTYPE ON VISIT.ID_TYPE = ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.ID_TYPE
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP(CITY.COUNTRY, CITY.NAME, ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME) 
ORDER BY 
    VISITED_COUNTRY, CITY, TYPE;
```

And it gives me following result:
[image]

But I should get result like this (only one label in row!)
[image]

Comment: [Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423302) As you state in your question this is "Oracle SQL" I've gone ahead and removed the other RDBMS tags.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can't see the images, but this sounds like it should be handled in your front end tool.

Comment: @andrew Just edited my question, hope now the images are visible. It should not be handled in front end tool, because it is oracle SQL study task in topic 'SQL for OLAP'.

Comment: Look into [GROUPING() and GROUPING_ID](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets#grouping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use case expressions to decide when to add your labels, allowing more control:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CITY.COUNTRY IS NULL
       THEN 'Summary-total:' ELSE CITY.COUNTRY END AS VISITED_COUNTRY, 
       CASE WHEN CITY.COUNTRY IS NOT NULL AND CITY.NAME IS NULL
       THEN 'Summary-country:' ELSE CITY.NAME END AS CITY, 
       CASE WHEN CITY.COUNTRY IS NOT NULL AND CITY.NAME IS NOT NULL AND ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME IS NULL
       THEN 'Summary-city:' ELSE ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME END AS TYPE,
       SUM(VISIT.NUMBER_OF_VISITORS) VISITORS, 
       SUM(VISIT.PROFIT) AS PROFIT
FROM VISIT
       JOIN CITY ON VISIT.ID_CITY = CITY.ID_CITY 
       JOIN ACCOMMODATIONTYPE ON VISIT.ID_TYPE = ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.ID_TYPE
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP(CITY.COUNTRY, CITY.NAME, ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME) 
ORDER BY 
    VISITED_COUNTRY, CITY, TYPE;
```

| VISITED_COUNTRY | CITY | TYPE | VISITORS | PROFIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | Florence | Appartment | 360 | 100 |
| Italy | Florence | Room | 330 | 92 |
| Italy | Florence | Summary-city: | 690 | 192 |
| Italy | Rome | Room | 300 | 80 |
| Italy | Rome | Summary-city: | 300 | 80 |
| Italy | Summary-country: | *null* | 990 | 272 |
| Summary-total: | *null* | *null* | 990 | 272 |

Or mix case expressions with `NVL` or `COALESCE` to simplify it a bit if you prefer:

```
SELECT COALESCE(CITY.COUNTRY, 'Summary-total:') AS VISITED_COUNTRY, 
       CASE WHEN CITY.COUNTRY IS NOT NULL
       THEN COALESCE(CITY.NAME, 'Summary-country:') END AS CITY, 
       CASE WHEN CITY.COUNTRY IS NOT NULL AND CITY.NAME IS NOT NULL
       THEN COALESCE(ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME, 'Summary-city:') END AS TYPE,
       SUM(VISIT.NUMBER_OF_VISITORS) VISITORS, 
       SUM(VISIT.PROFIT) AS PROFIT
FROM VISIT
       JOIN CITY ON VISIT.ID_CITY = CITY.ID_CITY 
       JOIN ACCOMMODATIONTYPE ON VISIT.ID_TYPE = ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.ID_TYPE
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP(CITY.COUNTRY, CITY.NAME, ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME) 
ORDER BY 
    VISITED_COUNTRY, CITY, TYPE;
```

| VISITED_COUNTRY | CITY | TYPE | VISITORS | PROFIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | Florence | Appartment | 360 | 100 |
| Italy | Florence | Room | 330 | 92 |
| Italy | Florence | Summary-city: | 690 | 192 |
| Italy | Rome | Room | 300 | 80 |
| Italy | Rome | Summary-city: | 300 | 80 |
| Italy | Summary-country: | *null* | 990 | 272 |
| Summary-total: | *null* | *null* | 990 | 272 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5nFrd0mw)

> it is oracle SQL study task in topic 'SQL for OLAP'

In that case it might be more appropriate to look at grouping IDs and use those to determine when to apply your label, as @serg suggested. If you're studying something then the tasks usually want to you use something you've recently been introduced to.

A similar approach with `grouping()`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN GROUPING(CITY.COUNTRY) = 1
       THEN 'Summary-total:' ELSE CITY.COUNTRY END AS VISITED_COUNTRY, 
       CASE WHEN GROUPING(CITY.COUNTRY) = 0 AND GROUPING(CITY.NAME) = 1
       THEN 'Summary-country:' ELSE CITY.NAME END AS CITY, 
       CASE WHEN GROUPING(CITY.COUNTRY) = 0 AND GROUPING(CITY.NAME) = 0 AND GROUPING(ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME) = 1
       THEN 'Summary-city:' ELSE ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME END AS TYPE,
       SUM(VISIT.NUMBER_OF_VISITORS) VISITORS, 
       SUM(VISIT.PROFIT) AS PROFIT
FROM VISIT
       JOIN CITY ON VISIT.ID_CITY = CITY.ID_CITY 
       JOIN ACCOMMODATIONTYPE ON VISIT.ID_TYPE = ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.ID_TYPE
GROUP BY 
    ROLLUP(CITY.COUNTRY, CITY.NAME, ACCOMMODATIONTYPE.NAME) 
ORDER BY 
    VISITED_COUNTRY, CITY, TYPE;
```

| VISITED_COUNTRY | CITY | TYPE | VISITORS | PROFIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Italy | Florence | Appartment | 360 | 100 |
| Italy | Florence | Room | 330 | 92 |
| Italy | Florence | Summary-city: | 690 | 192 |
| Italy | Rome | Room | 300 | 80 |
| Italy | Rome | Summary-city: | 300 | 80 |
| Italy | Summary-country: | *null* | 990 | 272 |
| Summary-total: | *null* | *null* | 990 | 272 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TDf7zEX0)